# How to copy data from one table to another with nested required fields in repeatable objects

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another. The schemas are identical except that the source table has fields as nullable when they were meant to be required. Big query is complaining that the fields are null. I'm 99% certain the issue is that in many entries the repeatable fields are absent, which causes no issues when inserting into the table using our normal process.

The table I'm copying from used to have the exact same schema, but accidentally lost the required fields when recreating the table with a different partitioning scheme.

From what I can tell, there is no way to change the fields from nullable to required in an existing table. It looks to me like you must create a new table then use a select query to copy data.

I tried enabling "Allow large results" and unchecking "flatten results" but I'm seeing the same issue. The write preference is "append to table"

(Note: see edit below as I am incorrect here - it is a data issue)
I tried building a query to better confirm my theory (and not that the records exist but are null) but I'm struggling to build a query. I can definitely see in the preview that having some of the repeated fields be null is a real use case, so I would presume that translates to the nested required fields also being null. We have a backup of the table before it was converted to the new partitioning, and it has the same required schema as the table I'm trying to copy into. A simple `select count(*) where this.nested.required.field is null` in legacy sql on the backup indicates that there are quite a few columns that fit this criteria.

SQL used to select for insert:

```
select * from my_table
```

Edit:
 When making a partition change on the table was also setting certain fields to a null value. It appears that somehow the select query created objects with all fields null rather than simply a null object. I used a conditional to set a nested object to either null or pick its existing value. Still investigating, but at this point I think what I'm attempting to do is normally supported, based on playing with some toy tables/queries.

Comment: Apparently what I'm trying to do works if I select from the pre-conversion back-up but not the new table. Investigating.

Comment: Seems I can select from the older back-up, but not from the new one. I think the data all follows the same schema, so from what I can tell this is BigQuery being fickle.

Comment: Can you give us a repeatable experience? Maybe share a table as public with the schema, or the instructions to re-create one.

Comment: Thanks! So after some investigation I was able to determine that when I moved data from one table to another to do the partition change (as well as one other data change), somehow missing nullable structures became populated with structures with null values. i.e. `IF(some_val_true, null, og.location) AS location` resulted in the location structure being present but all fields in it null. I think at this point it's me figuring out how to re-select data from the table and fix that issue.

Comment: Figured out how I got null values in required fields - I used SELECT AS STRUCT against a null value without a check beforehand to see if it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to copy from one table to another, and using SELECT AS STRUCT, run a null check like this:

```
IF(foo.bar is null, null, (SELECT AS STRUCT foo.bar.* REPLACE(...))
```

This prevents null nested structures from turning into structures full of null values.

To repair it via select statement, use a conditional check against a value that is required like this:

```
IF (bar.req is null, null, bar)
```

Of course a real query is more complicated than that. The good news is that the repair query should look similar to the original query that messed up the format